# C# Development on Unix/Linux (Anyone used CoreFX?)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, unix

I  have a C# server application with very few dependencies.  I'd be interested in compiling the C# on Linux or Unix without altering the code.  Has anyone used Microsoft's CoreFX ( https://github.com/dotnet/corefx )?  Specifically, are there major limitations as of now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of .NET Core is a subset of of the full .NET Framework so to check if your application works unmodified I'd suggest you simply [install .NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html) on a Linux machine and try and compile it.

Concerning major limitations, I'm guessing you mean functionality. .NET Core is geared towards web and console applications so if that's what your app is I don't think there are major limitations.

The latest version of .NET Core (Release Candidate 1) has a "Go Live" release which means if your app passes your tests and you are happy with it, you can host your app in production.
You can read more about the latest release candidate [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/README.md).
More info on .NET Core is available [here](http://dotnet.github.io/)